# Java: azure or azure-svc-mgmt-*

Tags: azure, azure-java-sdk, azure-sdk

So when I search maven I find what seems to be two different com.microsoft.azure SDKs. There is the com.microsoft.azure.azure and then there is the com.microsoft.azure.azure-svc-mgmt-* JARs. What is the relationship between them? Which set is recommended?

Answer (score 0):

My conclusion is to use the REST interfaces directly and avoid both of these. For my use case it will work better.